# Navigation component: When using FragmentContainerView, TopLevel destination fragment not showing Hamburger (Drawer) icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

I have an app in which I am using Navigation component with nav_graph. The problem I am having is that Hamburger Icon (also known as Drawer Icon) isn't showing up.

I am following this documentation - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/ui#add_a_navigation_drawer

My project structure is pretty straightforward.

MainActivity has `DrawerLayout` and it has `NavigationView` and `FragmentContainerView` to handle fragment replacements.

MainActivity
Layout - Drawer, FragmentContainerView, NavigationView
MainFragment -added with Nav_graph - This is the start_destination fragment on which drawer icon should appear.

OtherFragments- Layout connected with Nav_graph

My MainActivity looks as follows

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()

        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.mainToolbar.toolbar) 


        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(binding.mainToolbar.navHost.id) as NavHostFragment
         navController = navHostFragment.navController

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, binding.mainDrawerLayout)
        binding.drawerView.setupWithNavController(navController) //DrawerView is id of NavigationView
        
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
```

Interestingly enough, when I switch `FragmentContainerView` with just `<fragment>` which isn't recommended by the documentation, I could see the Drawer Icon in the `mainFragment` i.e top-level fragment, but still when fragment transaction occurs, it disappears.

With `FragmentContainerView` I cannot even see the Hamburger(Drawer) icon at all.

I followed the documentation and it should happen, but it doesn't seem to work at all. If there's a problem with my code or there's something I am doing wrong, please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated. If not, please point me to the right direction because this clearly isn't working.

If you want to inquire more about my project structure and layout info, feel free to comment, I will provide the necessary information.

Comment: What does your top level fragment's code look like? Is it calling `setSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: No I am using one mainActivity toolbar only for all fragments, so no toolbars in any fragments. @ianhanniballake